# How do I access or manipulate variables of one class from another in Xcode

Tags: objective-c, ios

I am a novice to IOS programming hence struggling a bit with the below problem. I will do my best to describe the problem and any help is greatly appreciated.

I have the following created:

- AboutViewController (.h, .m and .xib ) which has two subviews called - mainView, infoView. mainView and infoView interfaces are created in the XIB file.
- TestView ( View to deal with initiating, toggling between mainView and infoView )

TestView.h is as follows:

```
@interface TestView : UIView {

    IBOutlet UIView *mainView;
IBOutlet UIView *infoView;

    UILabel *lbltitle;
    UIImageView *imgIcon;
IBOutlet UITextView *txtInfo1;
    IBOutlet UITextView *txtInfo2;
IBOutlet UITextView *txtInfo3;



}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel *lbltitle;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIImageView *imgIcon;
```

TestView.m is as follows:

```
#import "TestView.h"

#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

@implementation TestView
@synthesize lbltitle, imgIcon;

-(void)awakeFromNib
{
[self addSubview:mainView];
}
```

---

In portrait mode the views are working great but when it comes to landscape mode, the views are all kinda screwed up. I tried to use the XIB but I guess you can only do so much so I decided to do this programmatically.

In the AboutViewController.m, I am trying to override willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation method and place the objects based on the orientation. When I put breakpoints, I can see that code is being called except it is not translating into the UI i.e., no change in the UI. What am I doing wrong ? Should I be approaching this in a different way. Any suggestions or guidance is greatly appreciated.

```
- (void)willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:  (UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
{

   TestView *t = [[TestView alloc]init];

if (toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft ||
    toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight)
    {
        [t.imgIcon setFrame:CGRectMake(10,74,165,190)];
        [t.lbltitle setFrame:CGRectMake(20, 10, 387, 21)];
    }
else
    {
        [t.imgIcon setFrame:CGRectMake(10,74,165,190)];
        [t.lbltitle setFrame:CGRectMake(189, 10, 387, 21)];

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the particular problem is you manipulate a view that you just created using

```
TestView *t = [[TestView alloc]init];
```

You don't display the view anywhere, so it sits in memory. You can apply all changes you want, but to be able to see them, you must first display the view:

Find the appropriate parent and do:

```
[parentview addSubview:t];
```

In more general terms you shouldn't be *creating* new views in the rotation handling code.

Comment: ok; here is what I am trying to achieve, please guide me in whats the best way to do it.

I have a tabview, each tab has its own xib file. On one of the tabs I'd like to show a series of pics and upon clicking on the pic, I'd like to flip the view to another one with more details about the picture that was clicked.

Comment: and by 'here' you mean where exactly?

Comment: I hit the "return" too soon; I have edited the comment - can you please take another look ?

Comment: That sounds like a perfect place to use an UITableView. Or, if you have few photos, just create a a scrollview, populate it with buttons that have your images as foreground.